# Different scalar result when calling User Defined Function from SQL Server using EXECUTE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, user-defined-functions

Usually, when using UDFs I stick to calling them via `SELECT` but recently needed to use `EXECUTE` and while testing it became apparent something was wrong. Here is an example of the behaviour being witnessed;

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.[fn_Example]
(
  @code AS NVARCHAR(2)
)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @result FLOAT
  IF @code = 'A'
    SET @result = 0
  ELSE
    SET @result = 0.2
  RETURN @result
END
```

When calling the above UDF using `SELECT` the expected result is returned;

```sql
SELECT dbo.fn_Example('B')
```

Output:

```
0.2
```

But when called using `EXECUTE` the result is incorrect;

```sql
DECLARE @rtn INT
EXEC @rtn = dbo.[fn_Example] @code = 'B'
SELECT @rtn
```

Output:

```
0
```

Have tried `WITH RECOMPILE` but it makes no difference, is there something I'm fundamentally doing wrong in terms of how the scalar UDF is being called via `EXECUTE`?

Comment: You declared `@rtn` as an `int`. It's the wrong datatype. An `int` can never store the value `0.2`; it isn't an integer.

Comment: @Larnu that is probably it, I'm so used to defining return values from Stored Procedures as `INT`.

Comment: If you're using `RETURN` on a SP you're probably misusing those too. You should be using `OUTPUT` parameters. `RETURN` is *meant* to used to return the success/error value of an SP (`0` for success, anything else for not).

Comment: @Larnu get the point. Your absolutely right in what you say, it is easy to miss simple stuff when you are close to the project. Yes, in stored procedures that is how I use return parameters, to denote success or failure.

Comment: @Larnu From [MSDN exec docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): "When used to invoke a scalar-valued user-defined function, the @return_status variable can be of any scalar data type." So for scalar functions `exec` returns the `return` result. Like you say it should not be declared as `int` in that case

Comment: @Andomar I think Larnu's point was making sure I wasn't misusing return values in Stored Procedures.

Comment: @Andomar I specifically stated SP's, not (scalar) functions. A function and SP are completely different object types. *"If you're using RETURN on a **SP**..."*

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[@Larnu's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57571368/different-scalar-result-when-calling-user-defined-function-from-sql-server-using?noredirect=1#comment101603239_57571368) was absolutely right. I was setting the return value to an `INT` when the UDF was expecting a `FLOAT`.

Should have used;

```
DECLARE @rtn FLOAT
EXEC @rtn = dbo.[fn_Example] @code = 'B'
SELECT @rtn
```

Comment: Is that not how you would do it @scientist_7?